# How can I detect keyboard input to play a sound with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a program that will play a sound when you press a key (or just type) on the keyboard.

I just started to work on it, and I am trying to use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` to check for keyboard input. I got to here with the code:

```
from pygame import init, key

init()

spam = []

while True:
    spam = key.get_pressed()
    if True in spam:
        print('KEY PRESSED')
    elif False in spam:
        print('NONE')
```

It works by checking if a `True` value is in `spam` (`spam` is the name of the list `pygame` returns). `key.get_pressed` returns a list of `True/False` values for every key, `True` if pressed, `False` if not.

The problem with this code is that when I run it, it only outputs `None`. This means that I am not detecting the keyboard input.

If anyone knows how to fix this, or a better way to do it, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) gets the states of all keybord buttons. It returns a list.
But, note the values which are returned by [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) are only updated when the key event is get events from the queue by [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get). In simple words, `pygame.key.get_pressed()` only works, if there is an event loop, too.

You can evaluate a specific key (e.g. space key):

```py
allKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
spam = allKeys[pygame.K_SPACE]
```

If you want to evaluate if any key is pressed, then you've to evaluate if [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) value in `allKeys` is `True`:

```py
allKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
anyKey = any([k for k in allKeys if k == True])
```

---

Another solution would be to check if the `KEYDOWN` event occurred. The next pending event can be fetched by [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get):

```py
keyPressed = False
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
        keyPressed = True
```

Comment: If you don't mind, could you explain this part: `any([k for k in allKeys if k == True]) `

Comment: @JackH. Thats very basic python. `[  ]` generates a list. The elements of the list are all `k`, where `k`  is  `for k in allKeys`, if the condition `k == True` is fulfilled. So it is a list which contains all elements of `allKeys` which are have the value `True`. [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) returns `True`, if the list contains any element.

Comment: Hi, sorry i took a while. It does not work for some reason. I don't know why. If you know why, It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It does not raise any errors, but it does not detect keys being pressed.

Comment: @JackH. the values which are returned by [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) are only updated when the key event is get events from the queue by [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get). In simple words, `pygame.key.get_pressed()` only works, if there is an event loop, too.

Comment: I will have to set that up then, Thanks